# Unexpected error calling ethereum contract using web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Unexpected error calling ethereum contract using web3.js

```
MyContract.methods.actual_balance("0xE8D.........").call({})
.then(r=>{
    console.log(r)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

I'm getting error:

```
{ Error: Returned error: err: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address 0x4..., maxFeePerGas: 3000000000 baseFee: 42784084648 (supplied gas 4700000)...
```

That is nonsense, I'm not sending transaction (send) but just querying state from local ledger. How is this posible?
Moreover, it was working an suddenly broke

Comment: Maybe try to remove the {} inside the call?

Comment: Thanks, but it initially was without {}. I added it trying to fix the problem

Comment: Can you share more details about the network and provider used? Ethereum mainnet, testnet, or some other l2 network. Web3 version used, and if it was working previously.

Comment: Try changing the `{}` to `{gasPrice:undefined}`. The reason it happens is because the current baseFee (eip-1559 value) is higher than whatever is getting set - usually explicitly setting it as undefined, in my experience, allows it to succeed

Comment: Thanks everyone. The issues was that web3 contract instance has gasPrice set too low, as  
natewelch_ wrote.

Answer (score 1):

web3 contract instance had gasPrice set very low.
You can use https://ethgasstation.info/ to get actual price.
I didn't knew that it does meters when you .call() not .send()

Answer (score 0):

If this function is just a `view` function then no gas should be required. Maybe your ABI was altered and when you make the instance of the contract locally, the web3 library thinks that this requires some gas cause it is changing the state